# Ubuntu 16.04 GNOME bluetooth devices not working correctly

Tags: 16.04, gnome, bluetooth, lenovo

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my new Lenovo E480 and have the issue that I cannot connect to any Bluetooth devices, the reason being that under Devices, I am only shown a long list of "All types" bluetooth devices who are not set up:

[image: Device List]

Here is some additional info that might be useful:

`lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00a2 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:2113 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:b023 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`rfkill list`

```
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Edit: Here's the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00a2 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 5986:2113 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b023 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Some more info:

In `bluetoothctl`, if I use the command `scan on`, it gives me

```
Failed to start discovery: org.bluez.Error.NotReady
```

Maybe this got something to do with it?

Any help would be appreciated!